# How to specify the I18n locale for registered users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n, pundit, globalize

I'm making an app that uses globalize to translate the db. I need to be able to create an UI for admins to be **only able to access specific locales so they can translate them**.

I am thinking two ways to do this. 1- use Pundit (see below), or 2- after admin signs in, I specify their locale (not sure how to do this). I'm open to other suggestions.

**Suggestion 1**

I started to use Pundit, because I thought I could use the scopes to specify the locale for restriction purposes. I need to have three levels of roles. A super user can scope all of the languages. A "europe" user, has access to all of the languages from european countries. And a country specific user can only translate for their country.

```
class IndustryArticlePolicy
  attr_reader :user, :model

  def initialize(user, model)
    @user = user
    @industry_article = model
  end

  class Scope < Struct.new(:user, :scope)
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
       @user = user
       @scope = scope
    end

    def scope
      if user.super_user?
        scope.all
      elsif user.europe?
        #see method below - don't think it works
        scope.where(I18n.locale.europe)         
      elsif user.role.present?
          #dont think below works either
         scope.where(role: @user.role.to_sym == I18n.locale)
      else
        scope.none
      end
    end
  end

  def index
    @user.super_user? || @user.role.exists? 
  end

  def europe
    I18n.locale = :ru
  end

end
```

**Suggestion 2**

(trying to figure out how to specify the I18n for a registered user)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack that I think I might use. I created nav links that only appear if the user is registered to designate them to the specific `I18n.locale` and I am using Pundit to restrict only registered users to be able to edit. If they're smart, they could change the URL to another country and they could have access that way. So, not ideal and not safe, but a start.